# Failed Connect CockroachDB using password include "#"

Tags: cockroachdb

so I try connect cockroach db using connection string, I have password include # but failed to coonect

here cockroach documentation: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/connection-parameters.html

when I use command below and insert password manually it's working

```
cockroach sql --url "postgres://taperaxxx@10.xxx.xx.xx:26257/sitaxxx?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=E:/ca.crt"
```

but when include password in connection string it failed to connect

```
cockroach sql --url "postgres://taperaxxx:#samplepassword#@10.xxx.xx.xx:26257/sitarxxx?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=E:/ca.crt"
```

here error when execute command with password included

> ERROR: cannot load certificates.
> Check your certificate settings, set --certs-dir, or use --insecure for insecure clusters. problem with CA certificate: not found Failed running "sql"

note: I try connect another cockroach db include password(with no #) in connection string and success.

if this bug or I miss documentation please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is a special character in URLs and must be encoded.

Use the [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) `%23` to send an actual `#`.

Your command line now becomes:

```
cockroach sql --url "postgres://taperaxxx:%23samplepassword%23@10.xxx.xx.xx:26257/sitarxxx?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=E:/ca.crt"
```